# Does Docker Support Redirect HTTP?

Tags: docker, go, web-services, docker-compose, http-redirect

I try docker to connect my services for study purpose.
It's all good when I try it in my localhost.
But when I try it on Docker, It's get error when I try to http redirect from product-service to my auth-service.

What I had try is instead using http redirect, I make a new request to auth-service, and It's worked and connected but it's get error when I try to redirect it in Docker.

This is my Redirect Code
I'm using golang and Gin-gonic Library

```
url := os.Getenv("AUTH_SERVICE_URL") // http://auth-service:8081  
c.Redirect(http.StatusSeeOther, url+"/refresh?token="+tokenStr)  
c.Abort()  
return
```

And this is My new request Code

```
url := os.Getenv("AUTH_SERVICE_URL") // http://auth-service:8081  
request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url+"/refresh?token="+tokenStr, nil)
log.Println("make request to", request.URL)  
  
if err != nil {  
    panic("Internal Server Error")  
}  

client := http.Client{  
    Timeout: 30 * time.Second,  
}  

response, err := client.Do(request)  
if err != nil {  
    panic(fmt.Sprint("unable to get auth request", err.Error()))  
}  

log.Println("REFRESH TOKEN", response.Header)
```

I just wondering, why when I use http redirect It's got an error on docker but it works when i try it on my localhost.
I'm using postman for testing and I got this error.
`Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND auth-service`

But it works when i'm using New Http Request code in my Docker with the same URL.

This is my product-service docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:

  product-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      AUTH_SERVICE_URL: http://auth-service:8081
      DB_DRIVER: postgres
      DB_USER: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      DB_HOST: postgresDB 
      DB_PORT: 5431
      DB_NAME: v_product
      DB_SSL_MODE: disable
      PORT: 8082
    networks:
      - auth-service_default
      - product-service_default
    depends_on:
      - postgresDB

  postgresDB:
    image: 'postgres:12.12'
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: v_product
    networks:
      - product-service_default
    volumes:
      - psql_user:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  psql_user:

networks:
  auth-service_default:
    external: true
  product-service_default:
    external: true
```

This is my auth-service docker-compose

```
version: '3'  
  
services:  
  auth-service:  
    build:  
      context: .  
      dockerfile: .  
    ports:  
      - "8081:8081"  
    environment:  
      USER_SERVICE_URL: http://user-service:8080  
      PORT: 8081  
    networks:  
      - user-service_default  
      - auth-service_default  
networks:  
  user-service_default:  
    external: true  
  auth-service_default:  
    external: true
```

Note: The Endpoint I try to redirect is : `GET` `:8081/refresh?token=JWTOKEN` and I use `See Other` Code for redirect, because It's redirect from `POST` request.

Comment: So if, I understand you correctly, Postman will be receiving a redirect to `http://auth-service:8081` but as Postman is not running within Docker (and connected to the appropriate networks) it will be unable to resolve `auth-service` (hence the `getaddrinfo ` error). Try redirecting to `http://127.0.0.1:8081` (assuming you are running both docker and Postman locally). Remember that the [embedded DNS server](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services) is only available to containers and redirects are actioned by the client.

Comment: Thank @Brits , it's works now and thank you for your explain. There's a lot I can learn from your explanation but maybe I have a little curiosity.  
First, I get from you explanation are:  
1. Redirects are actioned by the client (in this case Postman), so when it's trying to redirect, my postman try to connect auth-service with host `http://auth-service:8081` which is it is host inside the containers, so it can't reach it. So you suggest me to redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8081` because it's exposed port for client to reach it.

Comment: 2. When I try Make a new request to auth-service with host `http://auth-service:8081` inside my product-service it's connected because it's communication between two servers/containers (product-service to auth-service). It's got different when I use http redirect, It's not product-service anymore trying to connect, but the Postman trying to connect inside the container instead of the exposed port/network.

Comment: And this is what I curious about:  
1. How does the network in containers works, does it take effect to my redirect action or I'm just wrong specify the `host` because redirect is actioned by client?  
2. Is it right `the client` in this case is `Postman` ?  
3. Am I right if I said when containers trying to connect with `named host service`, the communication can be done if each containers connect to the same network and it's same like server to server communication?

Comment: Maybe, if you don't mind, you can answers my question so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [HTTP Redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) works something like this (see the link for a better description with diagrams etc):

1. The client (e.g. postman) makes a request (e.g. `GET http://auth-service:8080`)
2. The server responds with a redirect status (`303` "See Other" in this case) and the new URL (e.g. `http://auth-service:8081/refresh?token=blah`)
3. The client requests the new URL.

So, as per the comments, your app was redirecting to `http://auth-service:8081/refresh?token=blah`. The issue is that when the client, which is not a container, tries to lookup the IP address for the host `auth-service` it will not find it (it's not in the local `hosts` file and whatever DNS server you are using does not know the address). As such the fix is to return a URL that the client can access (e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8081`).

It's worth nothing that even if the client could resolve `auth-service` its likely the address would be something like `172.21.0.2`. This is a private address that is not accessible from the host (because you are using a bridge network). This type of network allows containers to communicate amongst themselves (within limits) and to initiate outgoing connections but provides no inbound access for the host or devices attached to the host.

External access is (generally) via [published ports](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports); that is the `ports:    - "5431:5432"` lines in the `docker-compose.yml`. These entries allow you to expose a containers port on the host (in this case port `5432` on the container is exposed as port `5432` on the host, but the port numbers can differ).

> 1. How does the network in containers works

Sorry - that's too much to explain in a stack overflow answer! The [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) are pretty good.

> 1.5 does it take effect to my redirect action or I'm just wrong specify the host because redirect is actioned by client?

The redirect is performed using the [http protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#section-10.3). [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html) is an [application layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) protocol; communication usually takes place over TCP/IP connections. It's worth spending a little bit of time to understand all of the different layers involved (there is always more to learn in IT!).

Within the underlying TCP stack the host (and other external systems) can only access the container via the published port. It's worth nothing that DNS (how the host name is mapped to an IP) and IP routing (can traffic from the host reach the container) are separate considerations.

> 2. Is it right the client in this case is Postman ?

Postman is fine. The alternative is to use a browser which will operate in much the same way.

> 3. Am I right if I said when containers trying to connect with named host service, the communication can be done if each containers connect to the same network and it's same like server to server communication?

Containers on the same network can communicate and Docker provides an [embedded DNS server](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services) that enables them to perform lookups (so map `auth-service` to the containers IP address and [`host.docker.internal` to the host](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host)). Its important to note that this embedded DNS server is not used by the host (and would be of limited use anyway because the host cannot communicate directly with the containers via their IP address).

Hopefully that helps - this can get quite confusing, particularly if you don't have much experience with networks. I would note that I often use Edge Routers/reverse proxies in this kind of situation (e.g. [Traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/)). With this you can just map one port (or perhaps two if you want HTTPS) and Traefik routes the requests to the appropriate container (this may just confuse you now but could be useful in the future!).